# kml divide map into regions

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api

in google map,

```
how to show Douglas county MAP in regions manner. (east, west, north, south).
```

These regions should cover with border and show the picker when click the balloon.

Here is my KML file, which shows the Douglas county, now i want to split under region.
(East,West,North,South, NE,NW,SE,SW)
[my kml file](http://www.fileconvoy.com/gf.php?id=g0434fb07e114bf9d999271929.277941788b847f25ce99ef&sts=13666333651827270194555f05abc559b99c327f18ba07f06236)

this kml output display here.[image: map]

i posted this post in stackoverflow, but it was closed due to ambiguous. can you please some share your ideas.

Comment: Slice it up the way Mapperz pointed out, then import it to Google Fusion Tables and then use the Google Fusion Tables layer in case you want to display these region on a google map and have them clickable.

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean like this? Sorry had to create an answer to post the image (regard this as a comment with picture attached for clarification)

Your KML Tiled with NW/NE & SW/SE quadrants

[image]

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned above, fusion table can be one way of doing this if you don't already have your boundary points.

Look at the following image taken from [http://simplyfound.com](http://simplyfound.com/worlds-facts/fact/28974/subregion/douglas-county-nebraska-united-states-north-america/)

Simply take a look at the javascript called map_subregion.js which has a very simple way of achieving this.

[image]